# Modal Animation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I am trying to get a modal animating with Tweenmax. It currently animates but the issue I am having is that I want it to animate from the top of the screen to the middle and stop there. Currently, it just animates into the middle.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="clickButton();">Testing</button>
<div id="container">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="modal">
      <h2>Testing Modal</h2>
      <p>Testing.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
clickButton = function() {
  TweenMax.to("#container", 0.3, {
    className: "+=active",
    ease: Power1.easeOut
  });
};
```

I have tried using CSS to do this:

```
#modal-container .modal-background {
  display: table-cell;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#modal-container.active .modal-background {
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJLbLw)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `transform` like this

```
#container.active {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

And your `#container` position `top` and `left`

```
#container {
    position: fixed;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Its may help you, here's my code for your issue 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/caffely/pen/qpwBPw)